# Compiler Error TS7053: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'Igame'

Tags: angular, typescript

Full error message:

Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'Igame'.
No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'Igame'. ts(7053)

interface:

```
export interface Igame {
  id: number;
  isStart: boolean;
  isFinish: boolean;
}
```

in the class component

```
public games: Igame[] = [];

public gameAction(id: number, action: string): void {
    const index = this.games.findIndex((game) => game.id === id);
    this.games[index][action] = true;
}
```

The error underline this code:

```
this.games[index][action]
```

The function gameAction is used to change a game status.
e.g

```
gameAction(1, 'isStart')
```

(game #1 is started)

Comment: What exactly you are trying to do with this line this.games[index][action]?

Comment: The function gameAction is used to change a game status.
e.g
gameAction(1, 'isStart')
(game #1 is started)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've resolved the compile error by adding an index signature to the interface, as the following code :

```
export interface Igame {
   [key: string]: any;
   id: number;
   isStart: boolean;
   isFinish: boolean;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`this.games[index]` will get you the Igame that you found the index of in the previous line.

So, you're doing the equivalent of

```
const index = this.games.findIndex((game) => game.id === id);
const Igame game = this.games[index];
const game[action] = true;
```

This is going to fail at the third line, because Igame is not an array,
or an array-like object, there is no such signature on the interface.

Comment: thank you for your answer. When replacing the 'action' parameter by a string, it is compiled Ok. like this : this.games[index]['isStart'] = true;